# Django FullCalendar Make Event Persist

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, fullcalendar

I am using the Full Calendar Js library to create a scheduling functionality. I used the `select` method which allows the user to open up a `modal form` upon clicking on a date(s). My code manages to save all newly added events onto the database using some sweet `Ajax`.

```
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'createEvent/',
                        data:{
                            name: name,
                            start: start.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                            end: end.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                            csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
                        },
                        sucess:function(){
                            alert("Event added")
                        }
                    });
```

Then I used the `loading` method to print out the corresponding events using some `django` magic:

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            loading: function(bool){
                if (bool){
                    {% for object in objects %}
                        var name = "{{ object.name }}";
                        var start = "{{ object.start }}";
                        var end = "{{ object.end }}";
                        var event={id:1 , title: name, start: start+"T14:30", end:end,};
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', event, true);
                    {% endfor %}
                }
            },
        });
```

Then if I were to refresh the page, logout then log in, the events will persist! However, I discovered a bug. As you may know, the full-calendar comes equipped with buttons to traverse through the months. Unfortunately, whenever this button is clicked, it acts like an refresh which causes the calendar to `render` duplicate events. As you may have guessed, the `for loop` inside the `loading` method gets run every time the button is clicked. How can I tell `javascript` to only run the `loading` portion only when the page is first loaded? I tried something like this:

```
   $(window).onload = function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            loading: function(bool){
                if (bool){
                    {% for object in objects %}
                        var name = "{{ object.name }}";
                        var start = "{{ object.start }}";
                        var end = "{{ object.end }}";
                        var event={id:1 , title: name, start: start+"T14:30", end:end,};
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', event, true);
                    {% endfor %}
                }
            },
        });
    };
```

But that does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not using the loading function correctly.

See: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/loading/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
    events: CAL_AJAX_FEED,
});
```

You will need an AJAX view in django to supply the data, rather than rendering it statically in a template.  From that django view you should return a JSON response.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def cal_ajax_feed(request):
    return JsonResponse({'foo':'bar'})
```